# Segmentation fault with CFNumberGetValue

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I'm totally perplexed at how this code is able to cause a segmentation fault. The code works fine on 10.5+ but seg faults on 10.4. Any ideas? The fault occurs during CFNumberGetValue.

```
CFNumberRef volume_num = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, CFSTR("Volume"));
if(volume_num != NULL) {
    float volume = 1.f;
    CFNumberGetValue(volume_num, kCFNumberFloatType, &volume);
};
```

EDIT: the code above gets a value that was added to a dictionary by the code below. mKitManager.GetKitVolume() returns the default value of 1.0.

```
AddFloatToDictionary(dict, CFSTR("Volume"), mKitManager.GetKitVolume());

static void AddFloatToDictionary(CFMutableDictionaryRef dict, CFStringRef key, float value)
{
    CFNumberRef num = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberFloatType, &value);
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, key, num);
    CFRelease(num);
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `volume_num` is actually a `CFNumberRef` and that its type is `kCFNumberFloatType`?

Comment: Yes! A default CFNumberRef is created and added to the dict before the CFNumberGetValue call is made. Strange.

Comment: what do you mean "a default CFNumberRef" ?

Comment: A CFNumberRef object that acts as a default value. In this case a kCFNumberFloatType type with a value of 1.0.

Comment: Can you humor me and add the code where it is created?

Comment: Sure, edited the question to include this.

Comment: @StephenBlinkhorn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1888/discussion-between-richard-and-stephen-blinkhorn)

Comment: Is `float` defined the same way in headers on 10.4 as 10.5?  That's my last guess, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the segmentation fault to this line:

```
mCurrentArray = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, array_capacity, newArray);
```

The issue being that array_capacity was incorrect (too small) for the array being copied. Why this would seg fault at a later point in the program I'm not sure exactly. Tricky one to track down and only caused problems on 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

- CFNumberGetValue(volume_num, kCFNumberFloatType, &volume)

It's likely that one of your variables is invalid (or points to invalid/out of range/null data).

The best way forward would be to compile with debugging enabled.
Enable core dumps to be generated (look at ulimit -c )

When your application hits the SEGV, a core file will be generated.
First rename it to something useful (so it doesn't get overwritten ).
Then open it with gdb.

From there you can examine variables to see which isn't what it should be.
You should also be able to view the source code when the core is open with gdb.

I'm not too familiar with OSX, but I'm assuming you'll have gdb/dbx or equivalent.